# Convert $(x-3)^2 + y^2 = 49$ to polar form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

**Question:** Convert $(x-3)^2 + y^2 = 49$ to polar form.

**Answer:** Applying $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, I find

$$x^2 - 6x + 9 + y^2 = 49$$

$$r^2-6x = 40$$

$$r^2-6r\cos(\theta) = 40$$

$$r\big(r-6\cos(\theta)\big) = 40$$

My answer appears to be wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try $x = 7\cos\theta+3, \; y=7\sin\theta$.

Comment: How do you know that $x=7cos(\theta)+3$? How did you compute that?

Comment: The equation describes the circle centered at $(3,0)$ (which is why $3$ appears in $x$) and with radius $7$ (which is why $7$ appears in front of both $\cos$ and $\sin$). Judging by the newly posted answer though, I may have misunderstood the exercise.

Comment: I see, I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct indeed we have

$$x^2 - 6x + 9 + y^2 = 49 \implies r^2-6r\cos \theta=40$$

that is the polar form of a circle centered at $(3,0)$ and radius $7$.

If we refer the origin at $(3,0)$ we obtain indeed $r=7$.

Answer (score 0):

To convert to polar form, set x=rcos($\theta$) and $y=rsin(\theta)=$ So we get $(rcos(\theta)-3)^2$+$r^2sin^2(\theta)=49$, expanding gives you $r^2cos(\theta)^2-6rcos(\theta)+9+r^2sin^2(\theta)=49$ then using the trig identity $sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=1$ yields $r^2-6rcos(\theta)=40$